# Font-face of org sub level indicator

Tags: org-mode, themes

Anyone know what controls the font face of this part of org markup:

https://www.screencast.com/t/n5wdrkktl9oQ

I've tried changing so many things in list-faces-display but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Try placing your cursor on the location you are interested in and type `C-u C-x =`

Comment: That seems useful, but I still can't seem to figure out how to get the information necessary to customize or target this font face.  I see it says:  (:foreground "unspecified-bg")  but I can't find that string anywhere in my elisp code.

Comment: That looks like something that would be defined in org-bullets. with the keybinding that @lawlist suggested you are looking for a line like "  face                 org-level-2". What are you trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it is at least not in any way I can get it work.  There are two font elements at play.  The Bullet, which is controlled by  face org-level-2 and then the * characters that come before it to indicate the sublevel.  I'm looking to customize sublevel indicator font.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found the solution to this, it was caused by a module I was using called org-bullets, the solution is detailed here:

https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets/pull/19